# Problem with rest web service?

Tags: java, web-services, hibernate, rest, jersey

I have a rest web service, that retrives data from my sql database using hibernate technology. While running, the web sevice throws error below

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sample.restlet.HibernateSessionFactory
    com.sample.restlet.EmployeeResource.(EmployeeResource.java:22)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.jersey.server.spi.component.ResourceComponentConstructor._construct(ResourceComponentConstructor.java:158)
    com.sun.jersey.server.spi.component.ResourceComponentConstructor.construct(ResourceComponentConstructor.java:148)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.resource.PerRequestFactory$PerRequest._getInstance(PerRequestFactory.java:175)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.resource.PerRequestFactory$AbstractPerRequest.getInstance(PerRequestFactory.java:132)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationContext.getResource(WebApplicationContext.java:160)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:64)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:111)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:63)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:543)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:502)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:493)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:308)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:314)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:239)
```

I dont get why this problem is coming. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

A `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class XXX` means that the class is found, but its initialization failed. Possible cause include:

- missing dependent classes.
- an exception thrown during execution of a static initialization block in the class.

Don't you get more info in the server logs? Any `Caused by`?

Providing the code of `com.sample.restlet.HibernateSessionFactory` might help too?